# /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librealsense2.so.2.50 doesn't exist despite ros-noetic-librealsense2 being installed in docker

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, realsense, realsense-camera

Goal: run this command inside a noetic docker `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch aligh_depth:=true`

Steps to reproduce:

1. `apt update && apt install -y software-properties-common`
2. `add-apt-repository universe`
3. `add-apt-repository "deb https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo $(lsb_release -cs) main" -u`
4. `apt update`
5. `apt install -y ros-noetic-realsense2-camera ros-noetic-realsense2-description`
6. `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`
7. Below command that throws error:

```
root@822516f273a3:~# ls  /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librealsense2.so.2.50
ls: cannot access '/opt/ros/noetic/lib/librealsense2.so.2.50': No such file or directory
```

I also removed the packages and installed from scratch but it didn't resolve the problem.

```
root@822516f273a3:~# ls /opt/ros/noetic/lib/librealsense2_camera.so
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/librealsense2_camera.so
```

```
root@822516f273a3:~# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/ros/noetic/lib
```

sys info inside docker:

```
root@822516f273a3:~# uname -a
Linux 822516f273a3 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@822516f273a3:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I suggest asking this question on https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues